# Standing during pesukei d'zimrah

Tags: tefilla, provenance, standing-sitting, pesukei-dezimra

What is/are the earliest origins of the customs to stand during various passages of the daily service before the Amidah (e.g. Baruch She'amar, Shirat Yam, Yishtabach)?

Comment: People who didn't sleep enough the night before.

Comment: @DoubleAA I would think they'd be doing *nefilat apayim*?

Comment: Or standing to *avoid* nefilat apayim

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer regarding Az Yashir. It seems that the minhag to stand for this is quite old. From [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/12/25/shabbos-shirah/) :

> In many kehilos the minhag is to stand during the aliyah of Shiras
>   HaYam from “Vayosha” until the end of the Shirah (Sefer Ketzos
>   HaShulchan 84, Badei HaShulchan 22). One reason is based on the idea
>   that the recital of the shirah by Moshe and Bnei Yisroel was
>   comparable to the recital of Hallel (Mishnah Sotah 27b). The halacha
>   is that Hallel is to be said standing (Shulchan Aruch 422:7), because
>   one is testifying to the fact that Hashem did miracles for us, and
>   testimony must be said while standing. Therefore, the custom is to
>   stand during the shirah, and **perhaps this is also the reason why
>   some people stand for Az Yashir during pesukei d’zimra** (Kitzur
>   Shulchan Aruch 14:4; Badei HaShulchan ibid.). Another reason for
>   standing during the shirah is based on the Zohar (Lech-Lecha 81b)
>   which says that Dovid HaMelech merited to be the ancestor of Moshiach
>   because he stood up in order to say shirah, as it says (Tehillim
>   119:62), “I will arise to praise You” (Siddur Tzelosa d’Avraham, pg.
>   168).

Comment: Quite old? The Kitzur Shulchan Arukh is less than 200 years old.

Comment: Shouldn't that raise (more strongly) the problem of the prohibition on reciting hallel daily?

Comment: @DoubleAA that's older than you and me combined! "quite" old, And how old is Hallel?

Comment: @loewian - It's "like" Hallel.

Comment: Please remove quite old, as there is no evidence whatsoever that it precedes the time of the kitsur. A custom in a 3300 year old religion can hardly be called quite old on account of being older than the folks discussing it.