# Congregational standing during Torah reading

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, torah-service

In a number of shuls that I have attended, I have noticed that the congregation stands for certain sections of Torah readings. Specifically:

- Aseret Hadvarim - The 10 Commandments
- Az Yashir (song at the sea)
- Parshat Zachor (when read only on parshat Zachor)
- The last verse of each book of the Torah prior to saying "Chazak..."
- When a Bar Mitzvah boy reads maftir

I see that we do have a question related to the [10 commandments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5424/5275), so you don't need to address this. Is there  any source or precedent for standing in any of the other occasions that I mentioned? Or is just a specific shul *minhag*?

Comment: [You already answered Az Yashir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56373/).

Comment: @Doniel that’s talking about Az Yashir recited as part of pesukei dezimra, not keriat hatorah

Comment: @JoelK I know. But if you actually read the quote you’ll see that he addresses Kri’as HaTorah at the very beginning.

Comment: Never saw it for a bar mitzva boy, not saying it doesn't exist, just that it is not a widespread minyan at least in Europe and Israel (or where I was in the US)

Comment: Note there is a controversy whether one should stand for special parts of the Torah (see e.g., bottom of [here](http://dinonline.org/2011/05/26/standing-for-torah-readings/)) based on the concern people will think some sections are more important than others